# calculate the font size of the textbox at change of it's height in vb.net 2013

Tags: vb.net, fonts, textbox, resize

I have to resize the all controls at the runtime. For this I have set the textbox's autosize property to false and assigned the new size, This changes the size. I also want to change it's Height proportionally. How to do that.

I have tried the link  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29140/Set-TextBox-Height
It didn't worked well.

Also this resize procedure should not make the form flicker. I already used form1.doubleBuffered = true, but no use.